# Github pages jekyll theme not working after installation

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I tried to install a couple of Jekyll themes on my [Github pages](https://snowformatics.github.io/) but the page is not showing the expected layout. I followed the [installation steps](https://github.com/amitmerchant1990/reverie) and the page was successfully build. I tried also other themes but I got the same behavior. How can I install the correct theme on my pages?

**How it looks:**
[image]

**It should look like this:**

[image]